# How to send a response from a request filter by adding custom headers in jersey

Tags: java, rest, jersey

I am developing a small password generator and I need to send a response from the request filter, if a value already exists in the database. In the response I want to add a few header fields.

Could someone help me? Thank you.

Comment: In a _request_ filter, you can use the `ContainerRequestContext#abortWith(Response)`. This will abort the request processing and skip the resource method. You can add the headers when you build the `Response`.

Comment: This worked for me. Thank you very much.